# C++ Visual Studio 2022 Shows suggestions for completely removed functions

Tags: c++, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

[image]

Function 'IsSubscribed' was there long time ago. Now it is removed but Visual Studio still shows this message.
Even after restart, even after project reload.
How to fix this?

Comment: The project database that Intellisense has created is out of date with the project's code.  It'll correct itself when it re-indexes.  You can delete the project's Intellisense database file to expedite the process (I don't remember the details on how to do that off the top of my head).

Comment: Please try close VS, go to the project's folder and delete the .vs and bin/obj folders, then reload the project.